# how to use build.binariesdirectory variable

Tags: c#, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I defined a post-build event for some of the projects in my solution, as follows:

```
copy /Y "$(TargetPath)" "$(build.binariesdirectory)Obfuscated"
```

Which results in an error:

error MSB4184: The expression `""".binariesdirectory"` cannot be evaluated. Method `'System.String.binariesdirectory`' not found.

Azure DevOps (and TFS build systems in general) are new to me, so any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Those azure-devops variables are only going to be available within a pipeline.  You can probably expand the macro section to see what is available for you on a post build task.

Comment: Thanks Matt, had to dig documentation and found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out for the post-build events had to use a different syntax (Windows batch script )

%BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY%\Obfuscated

So I used

copy /Y "$(TargetPath)" %BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY%\Obfuscated"

and the assembly was successfully copied.
[Microsoft docs link on Azure pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)